# Importing diagram from Visio to PowerPoint results in a large amount of objects that I cannot seem to animate

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

So I have a Visio diagram and I would like to animate it, so that I can tell a story and introduce one piece at a time.

The issue is that when I copy the diagram into PowerPoint and convert it so that it is more than one object, I get a ridiculous number of objects... like individual words and spaces are counted. Groupings do not stay either.

This wouldn't be too bad because they are in a logical order. But I cannot <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click to select a range of them in the selection pane, and trying to select by dragging the mouse is impossible because of how many objects there are, you will never get the ones you want.

I know there are not 131 rectangles here.

[image: Pic of the Visio document.]

Answer (score -1):

Visio cannot do animation natively, and any animation you can add will not transfer to Powerpoint.
However, try putting the shapes on layers.
Put the shapes for your first animation slide on layer 1, step 2 on layer 2 etc. Then show each layer in turn.